# How do I add files to a windows mobile device when deploying it?

Tags: c#, deployment, windows-mobile, compact-framework

I have a number of images and a CSV data file that I want to deploy to a windows mobile device along with my application. I'm using Visual Studio 2008 and C#.

I've added a "Content" folder to my project which contains the bmp images and the CSV file. When running my program on the emulator (by hitting F5) only the app is deployed, and not the "Content" directory.

I know I can add images to the resource file, but that isn't what I want to do - I want the images to actually be available on the device so that they can be changed without having to deploy a new application.

So my question is how can I set it up so that the "Content" directory is copied to the device?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

THe files from a "Content" folder will not be deployed on your device.

In order to deploy a file, right click it -> Properties -> select "Content" from Build Action

Answer (score 0):

Are the files within that folder also marked as content?

Answer (score 0):

In order to deploy files in the content folder along with folder,

Follow the below procedure,

Right Click the files inside Content folder--> select Propeties-->Build Action-->set build action as "Content" --> Copy to output directory--> set Copy always or Copy if newer.

Like this Do changes to all type of files(.csv,bmp etc)

Then Finally deploy into emulator or native device.
You will see the all files appearing  on the program directory of emulator or device.

Happy Coding -:)